# NameError: uninitialized constant RuboCop::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rubocop

I just cloned a rails API project from my github account. I developed this project before resetting my machine for some reason, and it was working perfectly but when I cloned it today and tried to run `rails db:create`, I got the following error:

```
$ rails db:create
rails aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant RuboCop::Error
Did you mean?  IOError
               Errno
C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Desktop/gentleman-api/config/application.rb:20:in `<main>'
C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Desktop/gentleman-api/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am not sure what I might be missing here, I'd appreciate some helpful feedback. Cheers!

Comment: I apologize if this is a silly question, but did you run `bundle install` and get all the dependencies first?

Comment: No it's not a silly question, but yes I have all dependencies installed

Comment: Would you be able to post a link to your repo on github, or somewhere code could be viewed? If not, can you recreate the issue in a dummy Rails app and post that? The issue likely lies within configuration but it is difficult to know the source of the problem with the current info.

Comment: Hi @Todd here is the source code from my github account [github link](https://github.com/ClaytonSiby/gentleman-api.git), the latest version of the code is under the feature/gentleman branch.

Comment: I cloned your branch and could not reproduce this, `db:create` ran fine. Can you run with `--trace` to see if it gives any other useful output?

Comment: Oh I finally got around the error, I noticed ruby hadn't been installed correctly on my machine, so I uninstalled and reinstalled it, everything's working as expected now. Thanks everyone for the responses. Cheers!!

Comment: Since the question was resolved in a way thats unlikely to be helpful to other readers you might want to consider just deleting it. It will most likely be closed anyways.